# Getting Infinite loop while using string.size()

Tags: c++, string, infinite-loop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#define MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE 512
#define MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE 20
#define DELIMITER " "
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    string buf = "PiCalculator(RandGen *randGen, int nPoints) : randGen(randGen), nPoints(nPoints) {";
    string buf1 = buf;

    // parse the line into blank-delimited tokens
    int n = 0;
    string token[MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE] = {};
    token[0] = strtok(&buf[0], DELIMITER);
    if (token[0].size()) // zero if line is blank
    {
      for (n = 1; n < MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE; n++)
      {
        token[n] = strtok(0, DELIMITER); // subsequent tokens
        if (token[n].size() == 0) break; // no more tokens
      }
    }
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    // process (print) the tokens
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // n = #of tokens
       int pos=token[i].find('(');
       if(pos == token[i].size())
            continue;
       else{
        cout<<token[i].substr(0,pos)<<endl;
       }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Using this program, I want to sort out the substring just before '(' i.e. PiCalculator. But, when I run the above program, m getting an infinite loop. Unable to sort out the problem. Can anyone help me ??

Comment: It crashes for me... and does not get into an endless loop. `token[n] = strtok(0, DELIMITER); // subsequent tokens` -> that is a nice way of crashing. I think you meant token[n].c_str() in there, right? Why are you using strtok in a C++ program anyway?

Comment: I recommend reading [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to get a better idea of how to debug this.

Comment: You know that [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok) returns `NULL` when no more tokens can be found?

Comment: `strtok` is an evil function. It modifies the source and returns NULL which may cause std::string constructor to crash. Generally I wouldn't recommend use it with C++ code, it's too hackerish.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Yes I know that.

Comment: Also, there are more "c++-ish" ways to get token delimited "words" from a string? For something more generic, look at e.g. [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), but for whitespace delimited tokens you could just use [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and the normal input operator `>>`.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: I am using strtok because I found the function easy to tokenize strings(found from google). I am a beginner in the language.

Comment: However, if you want to parse out e.g. `"PiCalculator"` as one token, `"("` as one token, `"RandGen"` as one token, etc, then you can't use the standard functions and classes straight off. You need to implement a proper tokenizer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: But, std::getline takes input from streams, but, here I have to take input from a string ??

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using the inherited functions, though there's an impedance mismatch with high-level templated C++. Just know your tool and beware the blade cuts.

Comment: Follow the link about `std::istringstream` in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want whitespace-delimited "words" (or tokens or what you want to call them) from a string, there is some functionality in C++ that can do it for you very simply:

```
string buf = "PiCalculator(RandGen *randGen, int nPoints) : randGen(randGen), nPoints(nPoints) {";

std::istringstream iss(buf);
std::vector<std::string> tokens;

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
          std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
          std::back_inserter(tokens));
```

The above code will copy all (whitespace delimited) "tokens" from the string `buf` to the vector `tokens`.

References:

- [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)
- [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)
- [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator)
- [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter)